# Javascript - either push(StringArray.split(",") not working or loop isnt

Tags: javascript, string, split

I am getting a variable amount of lat and lon returned from my database in the following config

`lat,lon*lat,lon*lat,lon` ect

So I split on the `*` which works.

Then I split on the `,` which seems to work if I print the spicific array cell.

When I try and do the below however it all goes to shit.

When I print

`cords[0, 0] + cords[0, 1] + "\r\n" + cords[1, 0] + cords[1, 1] + "\r\n" + cords[2, 0] + cords[2, 1] + "\r\n"`

and so on every row has the same exact lat and lon

```
 41.47033705-81.93612862
 41.47033705-81.93612862
 41.47033705-81.93612862
 41.47033705-81.93612862
...
```

I debuged this thing all night last night and then a couple hours tonight and I cant seem to find the error.

```
                var cords = [];
                var response = xmlhttp.responseText;
                var locs = response.split("*");

                for(var len = 0; len < locs.length; len++)
                {
                    var temp = String(locs[len]).split(",");
                    if (temp.length > 1)
                        cords.push(temp[0],temp[1]);

                }
```

I have also tried `cords.push(temp)` which doesnt work either

Comment: The variable cords is not part of your code snippet. Where is it declared? Also, String is not meant to be used with new. For string conversion, call String as a function and not as a constructor.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Vp7y6/ - not reproducible

Comment: @lightblade cords is declared just above the snip-it and I have tried both with and without new

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have 2 dimensional array you need to use:

```
cords.push([temp[0],temp[1]]);
```

instead and then address it as `cords[0][0]`, etc. In that way you have an array of N elements each of which is an array of exactly 2 elements.

Explanation why your code doesn't work:

```
cords[2, 1]
```

expression is treated as access to `cords` array with `2, 1` index. Whereas `2, 1` is 2 numbers with comma operator. The comma operator returns the last operand passed. So `2, 1` in fact is equal to `1` thus `cords[2, 1]` goes to `cords[1]`

Comment: @zerkms you're the man... or woman... what ever you are but you are it... thank you

Comment: @AMR: follow the avatar - I'm a cat

Comment: @AMR zerkms is not human not animal his his miracle just wait until zerkms is your next president

Comment: @zerkms it now works... You have just helped me track people all over the world and plot it on a map.... muahahaha /bow future president...

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var locs = "lat1,lon1*lat2,lon2*lat3,lon3";
var arr = locs.split("*");
var cords = new Array();
for (var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    var x = arr[i].split(",");
    cords.push(x);
}
//test
for (var i=0;i<cords.length;i++){
    document.write(cords[i][0]+" "+cords[i][1]+"<br/>");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

my approach...Each array contains latitude and longitude. 
http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/HWhMY/

```
var s = 'lat,lon*lat,lon*lat,lon';
var cords = makeArr(s);

console.log(cords[0][1]);

function makeArr() {
    var g = 0, arr = [],
        n = s.replace(/,|\*/g, ' ').split(' ').map(jn);

    function jn(s) {
        if (g<2) {
            arr.push(s);
            g++;
        } if (g>1) {
           g = 0, r = arr, arr = [];
           return r;
        }

    }
    n.forEach(function (e, i) {if (e == undefined) {n.splice(i, 1);}});
    return n;
}
```